# Moderator change: Flow retired

Tags: discussion, moderators

Just wanted to let you know that we've had a moderator step down due to time constraints:

[image: profile for Flow at Android Enthusiasts Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for enthusiasts and power users of the Android operating system]

Please join me in thanking Flow for his hard work over the past nearly two years!

Comment: Thank you, and all the best in your future endeavors!

Comment: As I already stated in chat: It was good to have you here as a diamond, Flow! We will miss that "character" next to your avatar – but hopefully do not have to miss you entirely!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks. I was just about to create a "I retired as moderator" post, but Matthew was faster.

[It was fun being a moderator for this site for nearly 2 years.](https://android.stackexchange.com/election) I can tell that it's true that one downside of being an mod is that you get to see all the low quality posts (and have to handle them), which is tiresome somehow. But on the other hand we have a site with good quality content and I think the community around it is great. [Just join the Android Enthusiasts chat if you don't believe me.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android) :)

I'll remain around on Android Enthusiasts.

Comment: Two years!  Wow, that makes me feel old :P.

Comment: You are more like the Android Enthusiasts Dinosaur :)

Comment: Congrats, Flow! You have been a great contributor all around! I wish you well in your endeavours!

Comment: Thank you for the hard work you've put in. @Flow, I am in sort of similar situ, real life, work has overtaken and not able to wind down to read some A&E or SO Q&A... cest la vie. Much continued success in your journey where-ever that road leads you to. :)